# PHP function to lowercase each character in a string except for the last one

Tags: php

I'm trying to lowercase every character in a string except for the last one that should be in uppercase.

Here is my code:

```
function caps_caps($var) {
    $var = strrev(ucwords(strrev($var)));
    echo $var;
}

caps_caps("HeLlo WOrld"); // should returns "hellO worlD"
```

Comment: Do you mean the last character of every *word* should be in upper case? Your description and your example don't match up.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to convert the string to lowercase first.

```
function caps_caps($var) {
    $var = strrev(ucwords(strrev(strtolower($var))));
    echo $var;
}

caps_caps("HeLlo WOrld"); // returns "hellO worlD"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the easy solution of this problem

```
function caps_caps($var) {
    $var = strrev(ucwords(strrev(strtolower($var))));
    echo $var;
}
caps_caps("HeLlo WOrld");
```

[Demo](http://eurekabd.com/Last_letter_upper.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
function caps_caps($text) {
    $value_to_print = '';
    $text = strrev(ucwords(strrev($text)));
    $words = explode(' ', $text);
    foreach($words as $word){
        $word = strtolower($word);
        $word[strlen($word)-1] = strtoupper($word[strlen($word)-1]);
        $value_to_print .= $word . ' ';
    }
    echo trim($value_to_print);
}

caps_caps("HeLlo WOrld");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, you forgot to do foreach, each elements.**

```
function uclast_words($text, $delimiter = " "){

    foreach(explode($delimiter, $text) as $value){
        $temp[] = strrev(ucfirst(strrev(strtolower($value))));
    }

    return implode($delimiter, $temp);
}

print_r(uclast_words("hello world", " "));
```

I hope this is the answer of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this piece of code.
function uclast($s)
{
  $lastCharacterUppar = '';
  if ( preg_match('/\s/',$s) ){//If string has space
      $explode = explode(' ',$s);
      for($i=0;$i<count($explode);$i++){
        $l=strlen($explode[$i])-1;
        $explode[$i] = strtolower($explode[$i]);
        $explode[$i][$l] = strtoupper($explode[$i][$l]);    
      }
      $lastCharacterUppar = implode(' ', $explode);
  } else { //if string without space
    $l=strlen($s)-1;
    $s = strtolower($s);
    $s[$l] = strtoupper($s[$l]);
    $lastCharacterUppar = $s;    
  }
  return $lastCharacterUppar;
}

$str = 'hey you yo';
echo uclast($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a multibyte safe technique that performs the title-casing with one call instead of two.  The string reversal and re-reversal is still necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YQSB5))

```
echo strrev(
         mb_convert_case(
             strrev('HeLlo WOrld'),
             MB_CASE_TITLE
         )
     );
// hellO worlD
```